# Value is not binded to the drop down provider unless next row is clicked on the grid

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, infragistics

I need to update a cell in a infragistics web data grid which has a drop down provider as soon as exiting that cell.

The problem is the value is not getting binded to the drop down provider unless the user clicks on the next row.

I've tried the Exiting edit mode event for this,but it's of no use.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 2):

The main point of having drop down editor provider is to bind it to cell key value and based on the key value to show a corresponding text value. If on cell exit you set a value (e.g. "Some custom value text") which is not present in the listed drop down item values, then 0 (zero) will be shown and nothing is going to be set.

You can handle CellEditing ExitedEditMode event, and from there to change the cell text or value with the helper methods (set_text and set_value).

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id="igClientScript1">
        function exitingEditMode(sender, e) {
            e.getCell().set_text("My Value");
        }
    </script>
```

It is important to remember that the cell value should be related to the dropdown's list of values in order to display the correct text representation of the item, unless you are using UnboundDataField, then there wont be any problems to set cell value/text on ExitEditMode client event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my scenario is different. I am selecting from that drop down provider which has an Id to it but that value is not getting binded until I click on the next row of the grid.

Comment: Everything should be fine then, if the dropdown provider is not bind to anything and you leave the cell, the value will be persisted. I have created a sample for your convenience:
https://filetransfer.infragistics.com/public.php?service=files&t=acd299d457a076a6bc2fcf94e4b69661

Could you let me know if I am missing something?